# How can I get a domain name to work with godaddy's hosting?

Tags: domain-name-system, hosting, domain, godaddy

I have a domain name that I acquired through google. I would like to get it to work with godaddy's hosting. How can I start to get that done?

Right now I have what godaddy calls a preview site. I would like to create a subdomain at my current domain to work with godaddys hosting. Is that possible?

Answer (score 3):

If you are just going to use a sub-domain and keep the main domain at the current location. You can simple create a new `A` record that points to the GoDaddy IP address of the server.

Comment: That is exactly what I thought was the case. But godaddy has this shared IP for the hosting package we acquired. They don't provide an ip or any other address to go around that. Suggestions?

Comment: Your IP address has nothing to do with your domain DNS record other than you point your website to that.

Answer (score 2):

It's easy to transfer domain names from one registrar to another. Here's GoDaddy's article on how to transfer to them:
http://help.godaddy.com/article/1592

Answer (score 1):

I just dealt with that.

I created another A record in my DNS setup:
 **subdomain.domain.com** and **IP** of your hosting

I know you bought the domain from Google, but it still tells you in administration_panel> domains> details, if Google bought it from GoDaddy or the other domain registrar, if you have it from GoDaddy then youre fine (Domain-wise fine. Hosting-wise? Thats a different story with GoDaddy :)) But if you bought it from the other company, then you will have to add Godaddy Nameservers too.